# Why is Form in Partial view not being validated by jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I'm gonna try to keep the code to a minimum here.
In my MVC3 application using c# I have a form in a partial view and the submit button in the main view. I have the [required] attribute on the model properties used in the partial view and also rules set out in an associated javascript file.
But when a user a doesn't enter any data on the field in the form no validation is executed and the application continues.
I assumed the following steps would be correct.
I have the Javascript file referenced in the main view.
The form Id is referenced in this javascript file as is the input id of the submit input form the main view.

Example of model property:

```
   [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Expected Return Date to Customer")]
    public DateTime? ExpectedReturnedToCustomer { get; set; }
```

Form tag in partial view:

```
  <form id="multipleenroutetoltslab" method="post"
```

Partial view is called via @{Html.RenderPartial();}

Input tag used for Submit.

```
   <input type="submit" style="width:100%;" class="styledbutton" id="MultiSubBtn" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript file reference in main view (part of a bundle):

```
 .Add("~/Scripts/CalibrationViewer/MultipleEnRouteToLtsLab.js")
```

Javascript file :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

$('#MultiSubBtn').click(function () {

    $('#multipleenroutetoltslab').validate({
        errorClass: 'field-validation-error',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) { //place the error method after the date picker component
            var trigger = element.next('.ui-datepicker-trigger');
            error.insertAfter(trigger.length > 0 ? trigger : element);
        },
        rules: {
            SentBy: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 255
            },
            DateSentToLtsLab: {
                required: true,
                dateFormat: true
            },
            ExpectedReturnedToCustomer: {
                required: true,
                dateFormat: true
            }
        },
```

The view Partial View:

```
  @model EnRouteToLts_RecByLts

  <form id="multipleenroutetoltslab" method="post">
  <p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SentBy)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(M => M.SentBy, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateSentToLtsLab)

          @Html.TextBox("DateSentToLtsLab", Model.DateSentToLtsLab.HasValue ? Model.DateSentToLtsLab.Value.ToShortDateString() : DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ExpectedReturnedToCustomer)
    @Html.TextBox("ExpectedReturnedToCustomer", Model.ExpectedReturnedToCustomer.HasValue ? Model.ExpectedReturnedToCustomer.Value.ToShortDateString() : null, new { @class = "date-picker" })
  </p>      
 </form>
```

There is more code the javascript file if needed.
I placed an alert after the $('#MultiSubBtn').click(function () { and it was fired so the file is being reached but rules are not being applied.
Also it should be noted when data is entered in the form it does reach the Post action.

No errors.

Comment: Can you show the `form` HTML that ASP.NET MVC is generating? Are there any errors on the page?

Comment: One problem:  You are not supposed to put `.validate()` inside a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method initializes the plugin on your form, and then the click event is captured automatically by the plugin.  So of course, you will have no validation on the form, because it has not been initialized properly.  Simply put `.validate()` inside the DOM ready event handler.

Comment: Refer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Comment: @Sparky's right. `.validate` should be called only once to initialize client-side validation for the form. If you include the Microsoft unobtrusive validation scripts, this is already done. All you need to do is add additional rules for this field, using `.rules`. That too should have on page load, though, not on click.

Comment: Yes, what @ChrisPratt said.  So when using `unobtrusive-validation.js`, in that case, any subsequent call you make to `.validate()` would be ignored.

Comment: All comments are appreciated, I removed the $('#MultiSubBtn').click(function () code, but is my problem not related to the fact that the submit <input> for the entire page is located outside the form in the partial view.

Comment: I've tried placing the script directly into the main view and the partial , it's still not picking up the validation ?